# A function allowing the user to choose beween a list of outputs

Tags: r

Just started R and I'm asked to make a function allowing its user to get a matrix with some descriptive statistics for quantitative variables. This was not too difficult but I have no idea how to let the user pick the ones he wants..

```
Descriptives=function(w=2,y=stats.data.quant.col) {

    ## w = decimals (2 by default)
    ## y = stats.data.quant.col (by default) OR stats.data.quant.row

    data.quant=data[,sapply(data, function(x) is.numeric(x) | is.integer(x))]

    stats.data.quant=apply(data.quant,2, function(x) c(Nobs=length(x),Moyenne=mean(x),Mediane=median(x),Variance=var(x),Ecart.type=sd(x),Etendue=max(x)-min(x),Coefficient.variation=sd(x)/mean(x),Deciles=quantile(x,seq(0.1,0.9,0.1))))

    stats.data.quant.row=round(stats.data.quant,w)

    stats.data.quant.col=round(t(stats.data.quant),w)

    y

}
```

Can someone give me a hint? I'm so lost right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interactively read user input. Here's how:

```
cat("Which of these fine output versions would you like? ")
cat("Version A: Statistical results")
cat("Version B: Pretty plots")
x <- readLines(file("stdin"),1)print(x)
if(x == "A"){
   # your code goes here
} else{
   # default output
}
```

You could also use the `scan` function instead of `readLines`.

Comment: I just saw your answer but thanks it seems a lot easier that the code I finally used

Comment: @Krisprolls Sure. Sorry, it didn't get to you earlier. Please click the check mark if you think this will be a suitable answer for future readers.